# creating a list by parsing rss feeds using java

Tags: java, android

Hiiii,
i want to create a list of articles by parsing the rss feeds from a website.Can anyone suggest me how to create such a list.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652273/parsing-rss-on-android

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the Rome library (http://java.net/projects/rome/). It'll parse different feed types and return you a nice set of java objects to work with.

Not sure how Android compatible it is though and the project page seems to have become a little inactive lately although the jars are still available and widely used (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492245/where-can-i-download-rome-rss-library-jar)

Comment: Rome has moved to Github: https://github.com/rometools/rome 
It's very hard to implement on Android, due to Android's half assed java.beans.x implementation and Rome's dependencies. You might want to check out https://code.google.com/p/android-rome-feed-reader/ instead, it's a Rome version for Android